# How to send Payment Transaction Failed Email copy to customers in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer, email-templates, payment

There is a setting in Magento

**Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout (from sales section) > Payment Failed Emails**

where you can add custom email id to receive it. But **I want our customers to receive Payment Transaction Failed Emails too**.

Any help reg this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration in Magento for that, therefore you will need to overwrite the function `sendPaymentFailedEmail` in the Checkout helper and add the functionality there.

If you are familiar with customization that shouldn't be a problem. The following changes need to be done.

Add the following in the `config.xml` of your custom module into the global or frontend `<helpers>` section:

```
<checkout>
    <rewrite>
        <data>Vendor_Module_Helper_Checkout</data>
    </rewrite>
</checkout>
```

Create a file in app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Helper/Checkout.php, copy the original function `sendPaymentFailedEmail` and change the code as follows:

```
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Checkout extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data
{
    public function sendPaymentFailedEmail($checkout, $message, $checkoutType = 'onepage')
    {
    [...]
    $sendTo = array(
            array(
                'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_'.$_reciever.'/email', $checkout->getStoreId()),
                'name'  => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_'.$_reciever.'/name', $checkout->getStoreId())
            )
        );
    //your added code starts here...
    //send copy to customer
    $sendTo[] = array(
                    'email' => $checkout->getCustomerEmail(),
                    'name'  => $checkout->getFirstname() . " ". $checkout->getLastname()
                );
    //end of your code
    [...]
    }
}
```

With that changes every payment failed notification would be send also to the customer.